# islamicUmmAlQura UIDatePicker is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, hijri

I am using islamicUmmAlQura UIDatePicker while developing iOS application as shown in the following
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tjhqp.png)

and I have TWO problems summarised as follows:

1- The date that appears in the text field is gregorian while my UIDatePicker is islamic (Hijri) see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a778.png)

2- Sometimes the days in the Textfields are above normal! see [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2xrw.png)

Comment: It depends on the code you have. Share a sample code. so I can find out the problem. otherwise check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an extension on github to convert dates. Have a look. mine is persian date so you just need to replace the below code with mine inside the extension:

```
datePicker.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .islamicUmmAlQura)
```

[https://github.com/Fridday/PersianDatePicker][1]